# Changing Fast Recovery Area destination

Tags: oracle, rman, archive-log

My database is running in archive log mode, but flashback is disabled because I do not need it.

The FRA is set to `/flasharch` mount point.

Now, I am going to change the FRA location to `/flasharch01` mount point due to space limitation.

What to do with archivelog in the old location. Do I need to move the old files to new location?

Could you guys please guide me step by step?

RMAN uses control file instead of recovery catalog.

Should I create a recovery catalog? if yes.. please how? I need steps please.

As, I can't increase the FRA location. The only way to change the location is the solution. Could you please share the steps how to move the old files and how to catalog them? RMAN using control file instead of recovery catalog.

Comment: What is consuming your FRA? What's your retention policy? Are there any obsolete files on it that you can clear up? Can you increase the size of `/flasharch` mount point? If you create new FRA you have to move old recovery files to the new location and catalog them you may also need to change initialization parameters.

Comment: Just symbolic link it, it's the easiest way

Comment: @JSapkota asked some important questions that you left unanswered.  Perhaps you don't need a larger FRA, but siimply need to improve you use of the one you have.  _IF_ the only files using the FRA are archivelogs and/or backups, then you do NOT necessarily have to move the existing files. You could just leave them in place and let them get deleted in the normal course of backing up a deleting obsolete.   And it is not a matter of rman " using control file instead of recovery catalog".  RMAN _always_ uses controlfile.  Catalog is simply an optional enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved. I have changed the FRA to new location.

```
alter system set db_recovery_file_dest='/flasharch01';
alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=750G;
```

Copy all archive log file which is generated in old and copy to new location.
using OS level copy commond.

```
RMAN> catalog db_recovery_file_dest;
```

Or

```
RMAN> catalog recovery area;
```

Or

```
RMAN> catalog start with 'New location Path';  
RMAN> catalog start with 'New location Path';
```

---

```
create PFILE='/flasharch/file_raiddb.ora' from spfile;




RMAN> crosscheck copy; 
RMAN> crosscheck backup;   
RMAN> delete expired copy; 
RMAN> delete expired backup;
```

```
alter system set log_archive_dest_1='location=/flasharch01';
create spfile from pfile=''/flasharch/file_raiddb.ora''

CREATE SPFILE='/flasharch/file_raiddb.ora'
FROM PFILE='/flasharch/file_raiddb.ora';
```

Comment: You should catalog your new fast recovery area after you moved the archivelogs. Maybe you also have to check if there is a controlfile copy in your FRA and change that parameter as well. Besides that you got it right :)

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right the catalog should be after moving archive log , so i have to edit the answer. For the control file copy could you please guide me how to check that control file copy is in FRA. Please also specify the parameter to change.